# Golang docker with cloud foundry CLI

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, cloud-foundry, docker-image

I use the following dockerfile and when I build and run it I got error that `**unknown command cf**`, I set the env and I expected that when I run `cf -v` it will print the version,what it could be ?

```
FROM golang:1.10.5

ENV CF_CLI_VERSION "6.40.0"

RUN ln -s /lib/ /lib64
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install curl -y
ENV CF_HOME=/usr/local/bin

RUN curl -L "https://cli.run.pivotal.io/stable?release=linux64-binary&version=${CF_CLI_VERSION}" | tar -zx -C /usr/local/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to change the last line to

```
RUN curl -L "https://cli.run.pivotal.io/stable?release=linux64-binary&version=${CF_CLI_VERSION}" | tar -zx -C /usr/local/bin
```

`/usr/local` is not in the PATH by default